# printing floating point numbers using scientific notation depending on size

Tags: c, math

I'm storing the result of a calculation inside a long double variable that I need to print out. I need a way to discriminate between large numbers and small numbers. For example If I want to print `tan(pi/4)` it should be 1, the same for the result of a multiplication like '5*3' I want to be 15 without trailing zeros. On the other hand, I want to represent small numbers like the elementary charge 1.602176634e-19 using the scientific notation. This is what I tried

```
void print(long double number) {

    long double i;
    long double tmp = ceil(number);

    if (fabs(number-tmp) < 0.00000001)
        number = tmp;

    long double r = modfl(number, &i);

    if (fabs(r) <.0000000000000001 && fabs(r) <.00001)
        printf("%.Lf ", i);

    else if (fabs(r) <.00001)
        printf("%.Lf ", i);

    else printf("%.19Lf ", number);
}
```

If I try to print the mass of a proton 1.6726219236951e-27 with this code I get 0, the rest of the quantities I mentioned before are displayed correctly.

Comment: " the mass of a proton " -- Please explain.

Comment: Use `%Lg` for the format.